# "Internal compiler" error when installing HHVM on Centos 7

Tags: c++, linux, centos, hhvm, hacklang

I need to install HHVM on my Linux server to enable my hacklang working. But I got this error message during installation

```
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [third-party/proxygen/CMakeFiles/hphp_proxygen.dir/lib/services/RequestWorker.cpp.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [third-party/proxygen/CMakeFiles/hphp_proxygen.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error may be due to the lack of memory, check how much memory does your server have by running the command

```
free -h
```

If you have not much free space try to add swap-space in your Server
Process to adding the swap space using swap file

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=64M count=16
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Now start to compile your Software

After compilation complete you can delete your swap file

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo rm /swapfile
```

Comment: Yeah, OoM is why I've seen this in the past too. HHVM requires quite a bit of RAM to compile -- at least 2G, probably more, especially if you're doing a parallel compile (`make -j`). I'd recommend making sure you have at least that amount of actual RAM, not swap, otherwise the compile is going to take absolutely forever.